# how to find vertices of polyhedron, given inequalities?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, polyhedra

I have a polyhedron which is defined by the following system of inequalities:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x \leq 2 \\ 
y \leq 1 \\ 
x + y + z \leq 1\\
x + y + 2z \leq 1
\end{array}
\right.
$$
I want to write a general algorithm that can find the vertices of this polyhedron.  This is my best solution so far:

0) Get in the form $Ax \leq b$

1) Since it is in $\mathbb{R}^3$, iterate through combinations of 3 rows of A, and see if the rank = 3 for those sub matrices.  this tells us that the inequalities intersect.

2) For each of those combinations that have rank = 3, solve the system $A' x=b'$ where $A'$ and $b'$ are truncated versions of $A$ and $b$ just for the combination at hand.

3) Use this solution $x'$ to see if it is inside the polyhedron.  If so, then a vertex is found.

I have not seen this process documented anywhere, and it seems to work on the cases i have tried.  am I missing anything in this algorithm?

Comment: If you're just interested in something that will compute this for you, try [Sage](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/discrete_geometry/sage/geometry/polyhedron/base.html#sage.geometry.polyhedron.base.Polyhedron_base.vertices). If you actually want to know an algorithm, maybe try looking at the source there. They also reference the [Frequently Asked Questions in Polyhedral Computation](https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/fukudak/polyfaq/polyfaq.html) by Komei Fukuda, so maybe you can find something there also.

Comment: You could combine steps 1 and 2 by starting with the augmented matrix $[A\mid-b]$ and computing the null space of each three-row combination. If it’s one-dimensional, the resulting null vector gives the homogeneous coordinates of a vertex candidate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CAS Maxima and my package "gt" (game theory):

[image]

Function "ext" compute extreme points of polyhedron.

Comment: This doesn’t really answer the question being asked.